# How could someone use Kanban or a similar method for community engagement?

Tags: communication, process, communication-management, facilitation

Looking for something process oriented, practical. Just some examples (as detailed as you care to provide) to have on hand. I'm having trouble differentiating between this example and, say, a small business.

Would appreciate your insights.

The wiki on community engagement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_engagement

Comment: Visualize it through a physical kanban board where the people of the community often gather or pass.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about project management within the scope defined in the [Help Center](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is quite broad and the concepts of Kanban and community engagement are not related to each other.

The methodology you are going to use to implement your work is something specific depending on the project itself. There might be many reasons to choose Kanban, instead of Scrum, of XP, or whatever. This represents the **HOW**.

Another subject is the goal you want to achieve. Community engagement might be one of the target of your business. In my opinion this represents one of the possible **WHAT**.

Answer (score 0):

I think an adapted Scrum methodology is a good methodology for community engagement. Kanban orients on the workflow to discover bottlenecks, which is usually not the biggest problem in community engagement, but helps to stay focused and keep track of progress:

- Using the backlog you can list all the stuff you want to do
- In regular meetings (*dailies*) you report progress, discover impediments, and might re-assign work
- During planning sessions you can put priorities on the backlog, identify *value*, and identify *effort*

Comment: [Scrum](http://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html) is a **framework** for developing and sustaining complex **products**.

Comment: @AlanLarimer Am I getting you right? You blame the not matching of Scrum to the described situation? My understanding was: do/adapt what ever you want but don’t blame Scrum if it doesn’t work. Many aspects of Scrum might help (even stand alone) in various situations.

Comment: There's no blame being placed on the framework. My comment was a clarification that Scrum is a framework not a methodology that focuses on products.

Answer (score 0):

Simply using any free kanban board account shared across the community might help visualise the tasks to be done and progress made in doing them.

Try LeanKit free for 30 days to see if it works and if it doesn't then try something else!